# Auto calculation not working in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am designing an invoice form where I ask user to add,delete multiple items along with their quantity and price. The total item is calculated and to that total price Tax amount is applied which gives combined total. I had managed to get the subtotal amount being calculated properly but somehow the tax amount is not getting calculated after entering the tax percentage which is messing the entire calculation. Not sure where I am going wrong?
Below is the HTML:

```
<fieldset>

                        <legend>Invoice Detail</legend>
                        <div class='row'>
                            <div class='col-md-12'>
                                <table class="table table-bordered table-hover" id="invoiceTable">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th width="2%"><input id="check_all" class="formcontrol" type="checkbox" /></th>
                                            <th width="5%">Item No</th>
                                            <th width="38%">Item Name</th>
                                            <th width="15%">Packing</th>
                                            <th width="15%">Price</th>
                                            <th width="15%">Quantity</th>
                                            <th width="15%">Total</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                        <!--<tr>
                                            <td><input class="case" type="checkbox"></td>
                                            <td><input type="text" data-type="productCode" name="product_id[]" id="itemNo_2" class="form-control autocomplete_txt" autocomplete="off"></td>
                                            <td><input type="text" data-type="productCode" name="product_packing[]" id="itemNo_2" class="form-control autocomplete_txt" autocomplete="off"></td>
                                            <td><input type="text" data-type="productName" name="product_name[]" id="itemName_2" class="form-control autocomplete_txt" autocomplete="off"></td>
                                            <td><input type="text" name="price[]" id="price_2" class="form-control changesNo" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;"></td>
                                            <td><input type="text" name="quantity[]" id="quantity_2" class="form-control changesNo" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;"></td>
                                            <td><input type="text" name="total[]" id="total_2" class="form-control totalLinePrice" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;"></td>
                                        </tr>-->
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-8">
                                        <button id="addmore" class="btn btn-success addmore" type="button">+ Add More</button>
                                        <button id="delete" class="btn btn-danger delete" type="button">- Delete</button>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-4">

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </fieldset>
                    <br>
                    <fieldset>
                        <legend>Amount Detail</legend>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-8">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <label><h4>Your Remarks</h4></label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-2">
                                <label>Past Due: &nbsp;</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <div class="input-group mb-3">
                                    <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1">Rs</span>
                                    <input type="text" name="due" id="due" class="form-control" value="" onchange="sumtotal();" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;" readonly>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="input-group" style="float:right;">
                                    <textarea type="text" name="due_notes" class="form-control" placeholder="Remarks Here" cols="30" rows="1"></textarea>
                                    <!--<input type="text" name="due_notes" class="form-control" placeholder="Remarks Here" onKeyPress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;" >-->
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-2">
                                <label>Subtotal: &nbsp;</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <div class="input-group mb-3">
                                    <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1">Rs</span>

                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="invoice_subtotal" id="subTotal" placeholder="Subtotal" onchange="sumtotal();" onKeyPress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="input-group" style="float:right;">
                                    <textarea type="text" name="subtotal_notes" class="form-control" placeholder="Remarks Here" cols="30" rows="1"></textarea>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-2">
                                <label>Tax: &nbsp;</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <div class="input-group mb-3">
                                    <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1">%</span>

                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="tax_percent" id="tax2" placeholder="Tax" onkeyup="sumtotal();" required="true">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="input-group" style="float:right;">
                                    <textarea type="text" name="tax_notes" class="form-control" placeholder="Remarks Here" cols="30" rows="1"></textarea>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-2">
                                <label>Tax Amount: &nbsp;</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <div class="input-group mb-3">
                                    <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1">Rs</span>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="tax" id="taxAmount" placeholder="TaxAmount" onKeyPress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;" readonly>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="input-group" style="float:right;">
                                    <textarea type="text" name="tax_amount_notes" class="form-control" placeholder="Remarks Here" cols="30" rows="1"></textarea>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-2">
                                <label>Bill Amount: &nbsp;</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <div class="input-group mb-3">
                                    <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1">Rs</span>

                                    <input type="text" class="form-control Bill Amount" name="amount_due" id="totalAftertax1" placeholder="Bill Amount" onKeyPress="return IsNumeric1(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="input-group" style="float:right;">
                                    <textarea type="text" name="bill_notes" class="form-control" placeholder="Remarks Here" cols="30" rows="1"></textarea>
                                    <!--<input type="text" name="due_notes" class="form-control" placeholder="Remarks Here" onKeyPress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;" >-->
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-2">
                                <label>Total: &nbsp;</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <div class="input-group mb-3">
                                    <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1">Rs</span>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="invoice_total" id="totalAftertax" placeholder="TotalA" onKeyPress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="input-group" style="float:right;">
                                    <textarea type="text" name="total_notes" class="form-control" placeholder="Remarks Here" cols="30" rows="1"></textarea>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-2">
                                <label>Amount Paid: &nbsp;</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <div class="input-group mb-3">
                                    <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1">Rs</span>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="amount_paid" id="amountPaid" placeholder="Amount Paid" onKeyPress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;" required="true">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="input-group" style="float:right;">
                                    <textarea type="text" name="amount_paid_notes" class="form-control" placeholder="Remarks Here" cols="30" rows="1"></textarea>
                                    <!--<input type="text" name="due_notes" class="form-control" placeholder="Remarks Here" onKeyPress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;" >-->
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-2">
                                <label>Amount Due: &nbsp;</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <div class="input-group mb-3">
                                    <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1">Rs</span>

                                    <input type="text" class="form-control amountDue" name="amount_due" id="amountDue" placeholder="Amount Due" onKeyPress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-2">
                                <label>Payment Date: &nbsp;</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <div class="input-group mb-3">

                                    <input type="date" class="form-control amountDue" name="paymentdate">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </fieldset>
```

And this is javascript I have written:

```
//adds extra table rows
var i=$('table#invoiceTable tr').length;
$("#addmore").on('click',function(){
    html = '<tr>';
    html += '<td><input class="case" type="checkbox"/></td>';
    html += '<td><input type="text" data-type="productCode" name="product_id[]" id="itemNo_'+i+'" class="form-control autocomplete_txt" autocomplete="off"></td>';
    html += '<td><input type="text" data-type="productCode" name="product_packing[]" id="itemNo_'+i+'" class="form-control autocomplete_txt" autocomplete="off"></td>';
    html += '<td><input type="text" data-type="productName" name="product_name[]" id="itemName_'+i+'" class="form-control autocomplete_txt" autocomplete="off"></td>';

    html += '<td><input type="text" name="price[]" id="price_'+i+'" class="form-control changesNo" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;"></td>';
    html += '<td><input type="text" name="quantity[]" id="quantity_'+i+'" class="form-control changesNo" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;"></td>';

    html += '<td><input type="text" name="total[]" id="total_'+i+'" class="form-control totalLinePrice" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;"></td>';

    html += '</tr>';

    $('table#invoiceTable').append(html);
    i++;
});

//to check all checkboxes
$(document).on('change','#check_all',function(){
    $('input[class=case]:checkbox').prop("checked", $(this).is(':checked'));
});

//deletes the selected table rows
$("#delete").on('click', function() {
    $('.case:checkbox:checked').parents("tr").remove();
    $('#check_all').prop("checked", false); 
    calculateTotal();
});

//autocomplete script
/*
$(document).on('focus','.autocomplete_txt',function(){
    type = $(this).data('type');

    if(type =='productCode' )autoTypeNo=0;
    if(type =='productName' )autoTypeNo=1;  

    $(this).autocomplete({
        source: function( request, response ) {
            $.ajax({
                url : 'ajax.php',
                dataType: "json",
                method: 'post',
                data: {
                   name_startsWith: request.term,
                   type: type
                },
                 success: function( data ) {
                     response( $.map( data, function( item ) {
                        var code = item.split("|");
                        return {
                            label: code[autoTypeNo],
                            value: code[autoTypeNo],
                            data : item
                        }
                    }));
                }
            });
        },
        autoFocus: true,            
        minLength: 0,
        select: function( event, ui ) {
            var names = ui.item.data.split("|");                        
            id_arr = $(this).attr('id');
            id = id_arr.split("_");
            $('#itemNo_'+id[1]).val(names[0]);
            $('#itemName_'+id[1]).val(names[1]);
            $('#quantity_'+id[1]).val(1);
            $('#price_'+id[1]).val(names[2]);
            $('#total_'+id[1]).val( 1*names[2] );
            calculateTotal();
        }               
    });
}
*/
//price change
$(document).on('change keyup blur','.changesNo',function(){
    id_arr = $(this).attr('id');
    id = id_arr.split("_");
    quantity = $('#quantity_'+id[1]).val();
    price = $('#price_'+id[1]).val();
    if( quantity!='' && price !='' ) $('#total_'+id[1]).val( (parseFloat(price)*parseFloat(quantity)).toFixed(2) ); 
    calculateTotal();
});

$(document).on('change keyup blur','#tax',function(){
    calculateTotal();
});

//total price calculation 
function calculateTotal(){
    subTotal = 0 ; total = 0; pastdue = 0;

    $('.totalLinePrice').each(function(){
        if($(this).val() != '' )subTotal += parseFloat( $(this).val() );
    });
    $('#subTotal').val( subTotal.toFixed(2) );
    tax = $('#tax').val();
    if(tax != '' && typeof(tax) != "undefined" ){
        taxAmount = subTotal * ( parseFloat(tax) /100 );
        $('#taxAmount').val(taxAmount.toFixed(2));

        total = subTotal + taxAmount;
    }else{
        $('#taxAmount').val(0);
        total = subTotal;
    }
    $('#totalAftertax').val( total.toFixed(2) );
    calculateAmountDue();
}

$(document).on('change keyup blur','#amountPaid',function(){
    calculateAmountDue();
});

//due amount calculation
function calculateAmountDue(){
    amountPaid = $('#amountPaid').val();
    total = $('#totalAftertax').val();
    if(amountPaid != '' && typeof(amountPaid) != "undefined" ){
        amountDue = parseFloat(total) - parseFloat( amountPaid );
        $('.amountDue').val( amountDue.toFixed(2) );
    }else{
        total = parseFloat(total).toFixed(2);
        $('.amountDue').val( total );
    }
}


//It restrict the non-numbers
var specialKeys = new Array();
specialKeys.push(8,46); //Backspace
function IsNumeric(e) {
    var keyCode = e.which ? e.which : e.keyCode;
    console.log( keyCode );
    var ret = ((keyCode >= 48 && keyCode <= 57) || specialKeys.indexOf(keyCode) != -1);
    return ret;
}

//datepicker
//$(function () {
  //  $('#invoiceDate').datepicker({});
//});


$(document).ready(function(){
    if(typeof errorFlag !== 'undefined'){
        $('.message_div').delay(5000).slideUp();
    }
});
```

Please help!

Comment: In which function do you have a problem?

Comment: To debug your code, try to remove part of your code and add them step by step with some `console.log()` to know if you get what you should get where your shoud get ! Then try to told us where is the problem (wich function, what you get and what you should get instead) so we can try to help you :)

Comment: Its function calculateTotal. The tax amount doesnt get calculated automatically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can not find `id="tax"` in your html code.You have used

```
tax = $('#tax').val();
```

Try to replace with

```
tax = $('#tax2').val();
```

And you will get the tax amount.

Comment: Can you alert taxAmount after this line?

 taxAmount = subTotal * ( parseFloat(tax) /100 );

Comment: Got it reosolved by changing the id to tax in html. Thanks